# Active Record Query to get optional has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Rails 3.2 and have the following and would like to load all the site placements with their native_ad_placement and sites. A NativeAdPlacement is also optional so could be nil. How would I do this?

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :site_placements
end

class SitePlacement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :native_ad_placement
  belongs_to :site
end

class NativeAdPlacement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site_placement
end
```

Comment: `SitePlacement.eager_load(:native_ad_placement, :site)`. The assocation being optional is completely irrelevant when it comes to assocation loading. But you do need to do nil checks later when using the records.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything - has_one is optional by default. If you're getting an error, check for any presence validations which could throw these.

Comment: Thx - using Rails 3.2